# custom CRUD in loopback remote-method for collection other than model for mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using Loopback for my project. I created a Model 'test' and a remote-method 'createOrder' for the test model.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (Test) {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {number} amount 
     * @param {Function(Error)} callback
     */

    Test.createOrder = function (amount, callback) {
        // Add log to the logs collection 
        callback(null);
    };
};
```

I am using MongoDB as datasource.

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "paymentDS": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "password": "",
    "name": "testDS",
    "user": "",
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

I want to insert logs into logs collection from the createOrder remote-method defined in test model.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have model for your Logs collection, you can do:

```
Test.createOrder = function(amount, callback) {
    // ...
    Test.app.models.Log.create(/*...*/)
    // ...
};
```

Otherwise, you could access logs collection directly from db connector:

```
Test.createOrder = function(amount, callback) {
    // ...
    Test.app.datasources.db.collection("logs").insert(/**/);
    // ...
};
```

Comment: can u give link of the official documentation for connecting directly to datasource?

Comment: here you go https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Working-with-LoopBack-objects.html. Read the docs yourself, that will benefit you a lot

Comment: well, I tried this method but still error : `Test.app.datasources.db.collection` is not a function

Comment: hmm, I'm not very familiar with properties of `datasource`. You should try poking around with it to see what properties it has, maybe look into `Test.app.datasources.db.connector`

Comment: going with the model way, for now.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create custom CRUD operations, you can use loopback remote methods implementation. Every model in loopback is inherited with Persistent class, you can use its default methods to perform CRUD operations from remote methods. Check my examples below,

**Create Operation**

Below example will create a document in MongoDB and also insert a record in Log collection.

```
Test.createOrder = function (amount, callback) {

    // Inserting object into database        
    Test.create({amount: amount, /*data to insert*/}, function(err, data) {

        // Adding logs to the logs collection 
        Test.app.models.Log.insert({ message: "order created", /*data to insert*/}, function(err, data) {
            callback(null);
        });
    });
};
```

There are more handy methods in the persistent model which can be used to perform create operations in different cases like `upsert`, `findOrCreate`, `save` etc.

**Read Operation**

Below example will retrieve several documents from MongoDB on the basis of filters applied and also insert a record in Log collection.

```
Test.findOrders = function (amount, callback) {

  // Finding objects from database
  Test.find(/** filters - Optional **/ { where: {}, limit: 10, fields: [], include: [], order: "", skip : 1}, function(err, data) {

    console.log(data);

    // Adding logs to the logs collection
    Test.app.models.Log.insert({ message: "orders finded", /*data to insert*/}, function(err, logData) {
      callback(data);
    });
  });
};
```

Here filters are completely optional. `where` is used to specify where conditions, you can use its sub-filters (like `gt`, `lt`, `nin`, etc) to get more condition-specific records. `fields` can use to select specific columns from the collection, `include` can be used to join different collections on the basis of relations. Remaining filters can be understandable from their names. For more information on filters, you can check the link mentioned [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html).

There are also available many useful methods in the persistent model which can be used to perform read operations in different cases like `find`, `findOne` etc.

**Update Operation**

Below example will update documents in MongoDB and also insert a record in Log collection.

```
Test.updateOrder = function (amount, callback) {

      // Updating object into database
      Test.updateAttribute(/* where filter */{id: 1}, {amount: 10, /*data to update*/}, function(err, data) {

        // Adding logs to the logs collection
        Test.app.models.Log.insert({ message: "order updated", /*data to insert*/}, function(err, data) {
          callback(null);
        });
      });
    };
```

You can every sub filter of `where` filter to perform the update operation. Again, there are many handy methods are available in the persistent model which can be used in several different scenarios (like `updateAttribute`, `updateAttributes`, `createUpdates`, `bulkUpdate` etc).

**Delete Operation**

Below example will delete a document from MongoDB and also insert a record in Log collection.

```
Test.deleteOrder = function (amount, callback) {

      // Deleting object from database
      Test.destroyById(123, function(err, data) {

        // Adding logs to the logs collection
        Test.app.models.Log.insert({ message: "order deleted", /*data to insert*/}, function(err, logData) {
          callback(data);
        });
      });
    };
```

Persistent Model also contains a different type of methods to perform delete operation based on different scenarios (like `destroyAll`, `destroyById`).

**Official documentation on `CRUD` operations**
You can also find complete documentation on the CRUD operations in loopback from the below-mentioned URLs:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-updating-and-deleting-data.html#deleting-data

Below link contains all available methods of the persistent model which can be useful to apply several BLs,

- http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel

There are also several methods available to perform bulk operations in the above link.

**Logging**

There ar already several extensions are available which can be connected easily with loopback to perform logging operations some of them are listed below:

- loopback-component-logger ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-logger)),

This can be useful to log operations in console or in database.